# Display triangles in 3D using Python

Tags: python, 3d, geometry

Disclaimer:  The context is a project I'm working on as part of my Master's degree.  I guess it qualifies as homework.

---

### Introduction

(feel free to skip to the bottom line)

Curved 3D surfaces are commonly displayed as a large set of very small triangles.  Each triangle has the following properties:

- 3 corners
- uniform color

Such that when they're all displayed together, you get the illusion of a smooth surface.  This is similar to the way pixels of a uniform color are used to get the illusion of a smooth image.

My project involves generating and displaying all the triangles that make up a given surfaces.  Assuming that I have code that generates a set of triangles, how can I display them?

The code that generates the set of triangles is in Python.  I'd prefer to use Python to display the triangles, but I'm not picky.

---

### Bottom line

How can I display a triangle in 3D using Python, when the input is the coordinates of the 3 corners of the triangle.

Answer (score 7):

Well, that depends, very much, like which OS you are using, do you need to be portable, etc.

But a generic answer is probably to use something like OpenGL, which is a portable API, and has Python bindings. http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

On Windows you can use Direct3D, but that isn't particularily portable, and I wouldn't be surprised if there is something special for OS X too.

Comment: yes use opengl and be happy, i will recommend using wxPython's wxGLCanavas, so you can have other UI elements easily.

Comment: If you choose OpenGL, you still have to decide on framework that would contain your OpenGL control. Some options are PyGame, SFML, wxPython, FxPy, Qt and pyglet.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misread your question. This is only for 2D:

You can use a wx.Canvas of [wxpython](http://www.wxpython.org/) or implement your application using [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/).

Comment: you *can* use 2D pygame, however that would need you to calculate the 3d to 2d mapping yourself. Fortunately, pygame has also a 3D api.

Comment: There's no wx.Canvas.  There is wx.Panel, generally for 2D GDI drawing.  There's also wx.glcanvas.GLCanvas for OpenGL.